# Progress Dialog Require Center Of The Screen

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, progress-bar, progressdialog

I would appreciate if i get suggestions for below issues.

I implemented progressdialog but its showing in left side of screen. Can anyone please suggest how to move it to center of the screen.

```
Dialog _ProgressDialog;

    var dialog = new Android.App.ProgressDialog(activity);

                dialog.Window.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Center);

                dialog.Indeterminate = true;

                dialog.SetCancelable(false);

                dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

                dialog.SetProgressStyle(ProgressDialogStyle.Spinner);

                _ProgressDialog = dialog;
                _ProgressDialog.Window.SetBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent));

                _ProgressDialog.Show();
```

Also, Can we achieve same implementation using ProgressBar as ProgressDialog is deprecated now.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: is this `xamarin`? If yes then add `xamarin` tag .

Comment: Sure @ADM. Updated.

Comment: I do not have any idea about xamarin . But i think its should show in center by default . See [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2311/get-a-progressdialog-to-show) , Its may help.

Comment: Add horizontal and vertical alignment to center. It might solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @ADM but couldn't work.

Comment: @SrustiThakkar, Please suggest property name as i couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I implemented progressdialog but its showing in left side of screen

The reason is that the `ProgressDialog` has a `TextView` at the right side of the `ProgressBar`. You could use `SetMessage()` method to set value.

> Can we achieve same implementation using ProgressBar as ProgressDialog is deprecated now.

Yes, you can. You could create a `ProgressBar`, and use `SetContentView()` method to make it be the content of the `_ProgressDialog`.
For example:

```
        Dialog _ProgressDialog = new Dialog(this);
        var dialog = new ProgressBar(this);

        dialog.Indeterminate = true;
        dialog.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

        _ProgressDialog.Window.SetBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent));
        _ProgressDialog.SetContentView(dialog);
        _ProgressDialog.Show();
```

And the result is:
[image]

Comment: Correct @billy, You are absolutely right with observation and that's the solution i was looking for. I would like to give 100+ up but unfortunately i don't have sufficient reputation to give vote as i'm newbie here but once i'll be eligible i'll sure do this first.

Comment: It seems to be someone voted as unclear or not useful. Very disappointed with that as that decrease my reputation whereas i asked valid question.